# fillmissing with only last 5 observations instead of all

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab's `fillmissing` [function](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fillmissing.html) to fill missing values.

If you have a matrix that looks as follows:

```
A = rand(10,2);
A(end-5:end,1) = NaN;

% this gives: 
A =

    0.8147    0.1576
    0.9058    0.9706
    0.1270    0.9572
    0.9134    0.4854
       NaN    0.8003
       NaN    0.1419
       NaN    0.4218
       NaN    0.9157
       NaN    0.7922
       NaN    0.9595
```

And you apply the function fillmissing as follows:

```
Afilled = fillmissing(A, 'previous')
```

then the corresponding matrix will look as follows:

```
Afilled =

    0.8147    0.1576
    0.9058    0.9706
    0.1270    0.9572
    0.9134    0.4854
    0.9134    0.8003
    0.9134    0.1419
    0.9134    0.4218
    0.9134    0.9157
    0.9134    0.7922
    0.9134    0.9595
```

Now however, the function does not take into account how many observations were actually missing (in this case 6).

I am looking for a way to take the number of observations into account before taking the last value. For example, only fill the missing observations based on the last 5 observations:

```
Afilled2 =

    i=1               0.8147    0.1576
    i=2               0.9058    0.9706
    i=3               0.1270    0.9572
    i=4               0.9134    0.4854
    i=5 % missing 1   0.9134    0.8003
    i=6 % missing 2   0.9134    0.1419
    i=7 % missing 3   0.9134    0.4218
    i=8 % missing 4   0.9134    0.9157
    i=9 % missing 5   0.9134    0.7922
    i=10              NaN       0.9595
```

Comment: You can do it on part of the matrix- `Afilled = [fillmissing(A(1:9,:), 'previous'); A(end,:)]`

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'take the number of observations into account before taking the last value'. From your example it looks as if you mean 'take the last nonmissing value but only substitute it for a maximum of 5 contiguous missing values'. Also do you need to handle more than one run of missing values in an array, and fill them with the previous nonmissing value in each case?

Comment: Simply, on a rolling basis, take the last value of not more than 5 observations are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB's `fillmissing` function doesn't have this functionality. Here is some simple code to do what you would like to do (fill along dimension 1 using the `'previous'` method):

```
% parameter: maximum number of observations to fill with a given value
max_fill_obs = 5;

% loop over columns
for col = 1 : size(A, 2)

    % initialize a counter (the number of previously filled values) to 0
    counter = 0;

    % loop over rows within column col, starting from the second row
    for row = 2 : size(A, 1)

        % if the current element is known, reset the counter to 0
        if ~isnan(A(row, col))
            counter = 0;

        % otherwise, if we haven't already filled in max_fill_obs values,
        % fill in the value and increment the counter
        elseif counter < max_fill_obs
            A(row, col) = A(row - 1, col);
            counter = counter + 1;
        end

    end
end
```

This works if there are multiple blocks of NaN values, filling in only the first max_fill_obs values within each block. For example, try running it on the matrix defined by

```
A = rand(20,2);
A(5:10,1) = NaN;
A(13:19,1) = NaN;
```

This is a vectorized version of the above code:

```
Afilled = fillmissing(A, 'previous');
Afilled(movsum(isnan(A), [max_fill_obs, 0]) > max_fill_obs) = NaN;
```

Comment: Yeah seems to work, but I was trying to avoid a for loop to speed up the computation.

Comment: Edited to provide vectorized version.